# Toggle Command Button

Tags: vba, ms-word

I was wondering if you guys can help me with this problem.  So I want a button that would show/hide a table in ms word.  However, I can only get the button to do either show or hide separately with my code.  Currently this code will show my table:

```
Sub Loan1()
'Hides Sections Not Used in Expanded Form
    Dim CollapseRange1 As Range
    'Set Which Range/Cell to Associate with Button
    With ActiveDocument.Tables(3)
    Set CollapseRange1 = .Rows(1).Range
        CollapseRange1.End = .Rows(25).Range.End
    End With
'If button is pressed then Hide/show CollapseRanges
    If CommandButton1 = False And CollapseRange1.Font.Hidden = False Then
    CollapseRange1.Font.Hidden = True
    Else
    CollapseRange1.Font.Hidden = False

End If

End Sub
```

I was hoping to be able to use one button to show and hide my table depending on the state of my table (hidden or unhidden)

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

OH I managed to figure out my questions.  Instead of

```
If CommandButton1 = False And CollapseRange1.Font.Hidden = False Then
```

I use

```
If CommandButton1 = False And ActiveDocument.Tables(3).Cell(1, 1).Range.Font.Hidden = False Then
```

I hoped this helps someone else!